# Item Right Tapped in ListView WPF

Tags: wpf, listview, right-click, onitemclick

Is there a way to get OnItemRightTapped event on ListView or GridView that works exactly like ItemClick, except obviously react only on right tap?

Answer (score 0):

You can add an event handler for mouse down and then determine the click source in the code:

```
    private void listView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ChangedButton == MouseButton.Right)
        {
            // Do what u need to do here
        }
        else
            e.Handled = true;            
    }
```